# PopUps in Safari

Tags: javascript

When I try to open a popup in Safari with

```
var win = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
```

it is opened as a new tab instead of a popup with the proper size. It is important to have boundaries, otherwise the layout is not good any more.

Any ideas why Safari on Mac dont allow PopUps?

Comment: You can never expect that the browsers opens a popup. Instead, update your layout to support various windows sizes (e.g. it may be enough to simply center your content/site)

Comment: You should simply forget popups. You could solve it with CSS positioning instead.

Comment: It is possible that this is something that comes from Apple's idea 'oh, let's merge iPad and OS X! They'll love it!' Well, it LOOKS nice.

Comment: I think the best way is to change the layout as all of you said! Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

Safari only allows popups upon user interaction. If you're waiting for other code to execute, you're going to have to open a new window on click, then change the attributes of that window once your code is ready:

```
var win;
$("#test-modal1").on("click",function(){
    win = window.open("", title, 'toolbar=no, location=no...')
});

// ...other code
// ...when ready, you assign a pageURL to the same window.

win = window.open(pageURL);
```